# BigQuery SQL - how can i know the min, max and avg?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here's the output :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfnzo.png)

Hello, i would like to know if it's possible to know the min, max and average "year_birth" other than looking for it manually ?

Here's my following code (it might be super bad, it's because i'm beginning with SQL)

```html
WITH clean_profils as(

SELECT *, 
REPLACE(Marital_Status,"Alone","Single") AS Clean_Marital_Status
FROM `neoma-bdd.data.profils`
WHERE Year_Birth > 1940 
AND Marital_Status <> "YOLO" and Marital_Status <> "Absurd"
AND Income IS NOT null 
) 


SELECT clean_profils.id, Year_Birth, Income, Kidhome, Teenhome, Dt_Customer, Clean_Marital_Status,
MntWines + MntFruits + MntMeatProducts + MntFishProducts + MntSweetProducts + MntGoldProds AS ALL_PURCHASES,
FROM `neoma-bdd.data.purchases` 
INNER JOIN clean_profils 
ON `neoma-bdd.data.purchases`.id = clean_profils.id
ORDER by ALL_PURCHASES

LIMIT 560
```

```
Bonus question, i'm doing a segmentation as follow : 

Quartile 1 : 1 rows to 559,75 rows
Quartile 2 : 559,75 rows to 1119 rows
Médiane : 1119,5 
Quartile 3 : 1120 rows to 1679,75 rows
Quartile 4 : 1679,75 rows to 2240 rows

how can i select only the 560 to 1119 rows based on "All_Purchases"

i tried self joining but it didn't help me at all :/
```

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text. You need to limit yourself to a single question per post. Please provide sample data for your tables and the result you want to achieve based on that data. Have you read the documentation for your DBMS regarding MIN, MAX and AVG functions and, if you have, what specific issues are you facing? It seems odd that you appear to know how to write CTEs but don’t know basic aggregation functions?

Comment: With respect to the previous comment, please see this question for showing tables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74936784/i-want-to-merge-multiple-records-into-a-single-record-in-bigquery/74937847#74937847

Answer (score 0):

It seems a simple question

```
SELECT AVG(Year_Birth) as Average
```

should provide the mean

```
 SELECT APPROX_QUANTILES(Year_Birth, 2) AS approx_quantiles
```

or if there are nulls in your data

```
SELECT FORMAT("%T", APPROX_QUANTILES(Year_Birth, 2 RESPECT NULLS)) AS approx_quantiles
```

should provide you with a min, median and max

```
SELECT
  APPROX_TOP_COUNT(Year_Birth,1) AS mode
```

should provide you with the mode